# How to generate a Stream of Points (X and Y Coordinates) in a grid?

Tags: java, java-stream, coordinates

I am learning Java as a beginner and I encountered the following question which I could not solve:

Implement the `generateGrid` method.

The method `generateGrid` has two arguments: `point` of type `Point` and `n` which is of type `int`. This method should return a finite stream of type `Stream<Point>` containing the `n * n` points that define a grid starting from the point `point` and then incrementing both `x` and `y` cordinates by one. For example: a grid of size `3` starting from a point `(0,0)` should look like the following:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
```

When in the stream they should appear in the order of the row first i.e. `(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (2,1) (2,2)`.

Implement this method body using a single stream pipeline.

The following method was solved in the previous part of the question (not sure if it is of any help here!)

The method `pointStream` has two arguments: `point` of type `Point` and `f` of type `Function<Point,Point>`.  Recall that `Function` is the Java equivalent of our `Transformer` functional interface which has the single abstract method `apply` instead of `transform`.  The method should return a `Stream<Point>` which contains the point `p`, followed by `f(p)`, and then `f(f(p))`, and so on.  Implement this method body using a single stream pipeline.

Some examples of use are shown below:

```
jshell> pointStream(new Point(0, 0), p -> new Point(p.getX(), p.getY() + 1)).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println)
(0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 2.0)
```

What I had attempted was to make use of pointStream and I came up with this

```
public static Stream<Point> generateGrid(Point point, int n) {
     return pointStream(point, p -> new Point(p.getX(), p.getY() + 1)).takeWhile(p -> p.getY() < n);
```

which returns (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) but I'm stuck on progressing further. I was thinking perhaps flatMap or map would help with this or am I on the wrong track totally?

Comment: isn't `limit(3)` defining that you only take three elements from the stream? so it seems to work as expected. what happens if you use `limit(9)` instead? or n^2 in general.

Comment: unrelated, but i can't believe your username wasn't already taken :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `IntStream` and `flatMap`:

```java
int n = 3;
IntStream
    .range(0, n)
    .boxed()
    .flatMap(x -> IntStream
        .range(0, n)
        .mapToObj(y -> new Point(x, y))
    )
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The first `IntStream` is for the x coordinates.
For each x value we generate another stream. This stream generates the y coordinates and creates a `Point` object for each.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a little math.

```
int size = 3;

List<Point> grid = java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, size*size)
.mapToObj(i->new Point(i/size, i%size))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(grid);
```

Comment: ~~ why use magic number when you already have a variable for it? ~~ Edit: very nice solution, probably better than mine

Comment: Technical debt don't you know.